# Angular 2 Service call is undefined from Angularfire 2 stream?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

I have an operation in which i grab some data from my firebase using angularfire2, map it and do some updates/checks on the data then i want to save it again but i'm having this weird issue where it tells me 'this.fs.getRiders' is undefined? but i'm using a service to create the stream, i'm not really sure what's happening here.

heres some code

```ts
 @Injectable()
      export class RoundService {

    public currentRound:FirebaseListObservable<any>;

constructor(private af: AngularFire, private as:AuthService, private fs:FirebaseService) { }

pullCurrentRound(serieUid:string){  

  return this.af.database.object(`series/${serieUid}/currentRound`)
    .flatMap((res)=>{
      return this.af.database.object(`rounds/${res.$value}`)
        .map((res)=>res)
        .do(this.roundUpdates)
        .do(this.saveRound)
    })
}

saveRound(round){

    this.fs.getRiders.update(round.uid,round)
      .then(snap=>{
        console.log(snap)
      })
}
```

And the error

```ts
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRiders' of undefined
at SafeSubscriber.RoundService.saveRound [as _next] (round.service.ts:57)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (Subscriber.js:232)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:174)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at DoSubscriber._next (do.js:82)
at DoSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at DoSubscriber._next (do.js:87)
at DoSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: @RaiVu Reformatting the error as a simple markdown quote makes it much harder to read the stack trace. Please don't make such edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` is not pointing to where you'd expect

```ts
pullCurrentRound(serieUid:string){  

  return this.af.database.object(`series/${serieUid}/currentRound`)
    .flatMap((res)=>{
      return this.af.database.object(`rounds/${res.$value}`)
        .map((res)=>res)
        .do(this.roundUpdates.bind(this)) // <<< changed
        .do(this.saveRound.bind(this) // <<< changed
    })
}
```

With this change `this` keeps pointing at the current class instance within `roundUpdates` and `saveRound`

An alternative way is using arrow functions but they are less convenient in your concrete case

```ts
pullCurrentRound(serieUid:string){  

  return this.af.database.object(`series/${serieUid}/currentRound`)
    .flatMap((res)=>{
      return this.af.database.object(`rounds/${res.$value}`)
        .map((res)=>res)
        .do(x => roundUpdates(x)) // <<< changed
        .do(round => this.saveRound(round) // <<< changed
    })
}
```

Comment: I find `bind` more convenient in this case because the number of parameters doesn't matter. In all other cases using arrow functions is IMHO preferred (already added to my answer). Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work.